# Navigation Controller becomes nil from todayextension

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate, today-extension

i have a today extenstion in which there is a button to launch the app,when the app is launched from this button navigation controller becomes nil

i have no idea why this happens ?

this is my code in appdelegate :

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    var storyBoard: UIStoryboard!
    var mainViewController: MainViewController!
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    if UserDefaults.getLanguage() == "ar" {
        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainAR", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swRevealController") as! SWRevealViewController
    mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MainViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    viewController.setFront(mainViewController, animated: true)


    if url.scheme == "open"
    {
        switch url.host
        {
        case "1"?:
            mainViewController.isTaxi = true
            break
        case "2"?:
           mainViewController.isPfp = true
            break
        case "3"?:
           mainViewController.isDarbi = true
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

please anyone can help ?

Comment: where are you setting navigation controller?

Comment: im not setting here,when i open the app through a button in extension,the app launches as expected..but inside the app i have a button which uses navigation controller to push another viewcontroller..since navigation controller is nil..i doesnt work

Comment: Use self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this line that ovewrites the storyboard navigation

```
self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

you have to embed it inside a navigation like this

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
```

Edit: before this line init isTaxi

```
mainViewController.isTaxi = // set it to true / false 
viewController.setFront(mainViewController, animated: true)
```

//

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    var storyBoard: UIStoryboard!
    var mainViewController:MainViewController!
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    if UserDefaults.getLanguage() == "ar" {
        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainAR", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }

    mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MainViewController

    if url.scheme == "open"
    {
        switch url.host
        {
        case "1"?:
            mainViewController.isTaxi = true
            break
        case "2"?:
           mainViewController.isPfp = true
            break
        case "3"?:
           mainViewController.isDarbi = true
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swRevealController") as! SWRevealViewController
    viewController.setFront(mainViewController, animated: true)
    self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    return true
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176481/discussion-on-answer-by-sh-khan-navigation-controller-becomes-nil-from-todayexte).